# Akka.NET - Cluster and ActorSelection path

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-cluster

I have an akka.net cluster and I want to send a message to actors that are both local and remote, and that all have the path "/user/foobar" (at least locally). Should I use ActorSelection, and what should the path look like in order to target both matching local and remote actors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear from the question whether you mean you want to send a message locally within one node in your cluster, or across multiple nodes.

If you just want to send it in one node, you can use an `ActorSelection` and just send it to whatever the desired actor path is (e.g. `/user/*/processingActor`). If you want to message across the cluster itself, you'll need to set up a cluster-aware Group router.

See the [docs here for router configuration](http://getakka.net/docs/clustering/cluster-routing#clustered-group-router-config), which is where you'll define the routees.

In a nutshell, you'll be doing something like this:

```
# inside akka.actor.deployment HOCON
/some-group-router {
  router = round-robin-group
  routees.paths = ["/user/*/processingActor",]
  nr-of-instances=3
  cluster {
    enabled=on
    use-role=targetRoleName
    allow-local-routees=on

  }
}
```